# Can not set List<Entity> in another Entity using Java Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, list, spring-data-jpa

I want to create a Tree structure like;

```
    istanbul fleet
        europe group
            a
            b
            c
            europe courier
                d
                e
        asia group
            f
            g
    ankara fleet
        h
        ı
```

I have repository, service, controller structure and I have 4 models Fleet,Group and Corrier, the hiearchy will be as shown in the tree. I have mapped entities as OneToMany as you can see in the entity classes.

I have service as;

```
public void createCourierForGroup(CourierRequest request, Integer id) {
        Courier courier = Courier.builder()
                .courierName(request.getCourierName())
                .build();

        GroupResponse groupToAdd = getGroupById(id);

        List<Courier> courierList = groupToAdd.getCouriers();


        if (courierList.isEmpty()) {
            groupToAdd.setCouriers(List.of(courier));
        } else {
            courierList.add(courier);
            groupToAdd.setCouriers(courierList);
        }

        groupRepository.save(mapToGroup(groupToAdd));
        log.info("Group with name: {} is updated with inner groups of: {}", groupToAdd.getGroupName(),groupToAdd.getCouriers());
    }
```

Fleet entity;

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Fleet{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    private String fleetName;
    
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private List<CarRegistry> carRegistries;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "fleet",fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private List<Group> groups;

}
```

Group entity;

```
@Entity(name = "group_table")
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String groupName;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private List<CarRegistry> carRegistries;

    @ManyToOne
    private Fleet fleet;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group",fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private List<Courier> couriers;


}
```

and response as

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "fleetName": "Avrupa fleet",
            "carRegistries": [],
            "groups": []
        }
    ],
    "message": "Fleets are listed successfully.",
    "status": 200
}
```

My repositories are like this, nothing fancy just data jpa.

```
@Repository
public interface GroupRepository extends JpaRepository<Group, Integer> {
}
```

As you can see groups are empty, what can be wrong?

I did try List.Of() method or creating new List and passing it to save method but it didn't work.

Comment: can you post your repository code

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried saving the courier first before adding it to the list?

Also `List.of()` creates an immutable list.
https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-collections-factory-methods

If the courier list is empty, you can add the new courier to it and set it to the group.

P.S: I guess this line `GroupResponse groupToAdd = getGroupById(id);` is converting the Group entity to GroupResponse and `mapToGroup(groupToAdd)` is mapping the GroupResponse to Group entity before saving.